# How to keep a button from changing back the value of the variable

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a simple project for school but got stuck on this one problem.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
     var clickCount = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        labelName.text=" \(clickCount) "
        clickCount+=1
    }

    @IBAction func upgrade(_ sender: Any) {
        clickCount+=2
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a simple clicker game where you "get" coins by clicking on the buttonClick button. I added another button called "upgrade", which increases the amount of coins you get per click. However, I would like to implement an incremental click system where there is a base amount of coins added every time but can increase the amount per click permanently each time you "upgrade" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a "increment value" variable on your button click function, e.g.:

```
// MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!

var clickCount = 0
var scoreIncrement = 1

// MARK: Life cycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: Any) {
    labelName.text=" \(clickCount) "
    clickCount += scoreIncrement
}

@IBAction func upgrade(_ sender: Any) {
    scoreIncrement+=1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because you can't see it. It is actually adding +2 but you are not assigning it to the label in the upgrade function.
Try doing this

```
@IBAction func upgrade(_ sender: Any) {
    labelName.text=" \(clickCount) "
    clickCount+=2
}
```